# Remove read-only modifier for callable signature

Tags: typescript

A function initially doesn't allow to change read-only properties (e.g. `name` in ES6):

```
let foo = function (n: number) {
    return n;
}

foo.name = 'not foo'; // Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property
```

In order to work this around, `Writable` utility type from the reference was used:

```
type Writable<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
```

1. Read-only `name` is not affected by an intersection:

```
let writableFoo: typeof foo & { name: string } = foo;
writableFoo.name = 'not foo'; // Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property
```

2. `Writable` doesn't get `name` from function type and is not callable:

```
let writableFoo: Writable<typeof foo> = foo;
writableFoo.name = 'not foo'; // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Writable<(n: number) => number>'
writableFoo(1); // This expression is not callable
```

3. `Writable` gets `name` from `Function` but is still not callable:

```
let writableFoo: Writable<Function> = foo;
writableFoo.name = 'not foo';
writableFoo(1); // This expression is not callable
```

4. `Omit` uses index signature and is not callable either:

```
let writableFoo: Omit<typeof foo, 'name'> & { name: string } = foo;
writableFoo.name = 'not foo';
writableFoo(1); // This expression is not callable
```

The objective here is to type `writableFoo` to keep `writableFoo` callable and allow `name` to be changed, preferably without modifying other properties with `Writable`. It doesn't try to solve a specific coding problem but investigate specified type issues.

Why does 1 not affect `readonly` modifier by intersection type?

Why does 2 not get `name` despite it's recognized for `typeof foo` as `foo.name`?

How can 2-4 get call signature while removing `readonly` modifier from `name`?

Comment: If I look on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), it specifies that if you want to change it, you would need to use `Object.defineProperty`, as it is configurable you could override it that way

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks, that's correct (but it won't work for writable non-configurable property). As I noted, the goal is to not solve a coding problem but investigate TS typing issues.

Comment: Why does 1 not affect readonly modifier by union type?
`typeof foo & { name: string }` creates an intersection instead of an union `typeof foo | { name: string }`

Comment: @NareshPingale Thanks for noticing, fixed the term. I expected it to be an intersection, a union won't work there.

Comment: Even if you do `foo.name = 'not foo';` `foo.name` will still print "foo" so what's the goal here?

Comment: @TSR This is browser-dependent, `name` is read-only by specs but can be writable in older browsers. As I mentioned, the goal is to solve described problem with types, `name` is just an example in existent TS typings. That a property is `readonly` in TS doesn't mean it's not writable at runtime.

Comment: @EstusFlask Does my new answer below help? If so please accept

Answer (score 2):

With this you can both call and write `name`

```
interface Foo extends Function{
    name: string
}
const d: Foo = function(){}
d.name ='not foo'
d()
```

> Thanks. It technically solves the problem but Function ignores the
> signature of the function, d('should cause TS error', 'for unexpected
> args') (this wasn't mentioned in the question but seems to be a
> reasonable requirement). Also const itself is able to remove the error
> because it's treated differently than let

```
type  Incrementer = (x: number)=>string
interface Foo extends Incrementer{
    name: string
}
let d: Foo = (x)=>'a'+x
d.name ='not foo'
d(1)
d('s') // string not expceted must be number
```

If you want a general answer, here is your `Writable`

```
interface Writable<T extends (...args: any) => any> {
    (...arg: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;

    name: string
}

type  Incrementer = (x: number, y: boolean) => string

let d: Writable<Incrementer> = (x, y) => 'a' + x + y
d.name = 'not foo' // no error
d(1, true) // no error
d('d', true)  // 'd' is not assignable to number
d(2, 1) // 1 is not assignable to boolean
```

Comment: Thanks. It technically solves the problem but `Function` ignores the signature of the function, `d('should cause TS error', 'for unexpected args')` (this wasn't mentioned in the question but seems to be a reasonable requirement). Also `const` itself is able to remove the error because it's treated differently than `let`.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. Just like to add that you can write callable signature right inside interface declaration like: `interface Foo { (n: number): number; name: string }` no need to `extends`.

Comment: @EstusFlask check last edit. I improved the answer with a general answer

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. I'll leave the question open because I'm still interested in an explanation regarding TS internals why callable signatures behave like they do here ("why" parts from the question). If there's a way to infer the signature without specifying function type explicitly, it would be the preferable solution here.